# Query on removing the X from title bar of a window

Tags: powershell

I am not that well versed with PS, however I have managed to get a code (not mine) from another person. The code is to restart computers remotely.
The code goes like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "Microsoft.VisualBasic") | Out-Null
$Title = "Patching Reboot"
$Message = "In order to apply urgent security patches and updates to your computer, your machine must be restarted.
```

The intent is not to allow users to exit out of this box, at the moment, when the user exits the purpose of this is defeated.

Comment: Please clarify your intent: Should there be no interactive elements shown at all, or just a single button for acknowledgement, before proceeding?

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is the WindowStyle you select.
All but one will display the close button...

[MS Docs - Window.WindowStyle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstyle?view=netframework-4.5.2)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$window = New-Object System.Windows.Window
$window.WindowStyle = "None"
$Text = @'
=== Patching Reboot ===

In order to apply urgent security patches
and updates to your computer, your machine
must be restarted.
'@
$window.AddText($Text)
$window.Height = '300'
$window.Width = '500'
$window.FontSize = 24
$window.Show()
```

When you're done, just close the window...

```
$window.Close()
```

For some more information, have a look at [PowerShell School of WPF](https://schoolofwpf.wordpress.com/)